# Nginx + dns settings

Tags: dns, nginx

I have www.exampledomain1.com, www.exampledomain2.com  and i build sites on VPS  IP:  11.22.333.444 (example)  and nginx.

what i did:

for www.exampledomain1.com : 
DNS setting:

```
Type    Host                    IP
 A     www.exampledomain1.com   11.22.333.444
```

Nginx setting (short):

```
server{
       server_name  www.exampledomain1.com;
}
```

for www.exampledomain2.com : 
DNS setting:

```
Type    Host                    IP
 A      www.exampledomain2.com  11.22.333.444
```

Nginx setting (short):

```
server{
       server_name  www.exampledomain2.com;
}
```

What i thought that: when  www.exampledomain1.com is fire in browser, my nginx is receiving "Host" (server_name www.exampledomain.com)   and then lunching my site from proper root. What do i do wrong?

Comment: What happens now when you go to either one of those domains?

Comment: It works ok. The point was i should wait for DNS change a bit longer.

Comment: I downvoted the question because according to the OPs comment, there was nothing wrong with the presented configuration, just a TTL issue.